# MySql add data from multiple table to one column of one table

Tags: mysql

Currently I am Working in One project here i have two tables names a and b they both have one column name preference now i want to copy data from table a and b's preference column to another table call pqr according to it's it and the id of both table a and b is different

Comment: You can apply join on table a,b and insert data in another table c.

Comment: Look into SQL's `UNION`.

Answer (score 0):

If both tables are truly the same schema:

```
insert into pqr
select  * from a 
union all 
select * from b;
```

Otherwise, you'll have to specify the column names (the column list for pqr is optional if you are specifying a value for all columns and selecting columns in the same order as pqr's schema):

```
insert into pqr (col_name)
select col_name from a 
union all 
select col_name from b;
```

This query should work for you.

Hope this works.